# Why can't I display this page inside my own page?

Tags: html, iframe

This is the page I'm trying to display inside my own page :
http://matchhistory.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/EUW1/2468687321

I've tried different ways to achieve it, but they lead to a blank canvas.

---

Method 1 (unsuccessful) :

```
<div> 
<object type="text/html" data="http://matchhistory.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/EUW1/2468687321" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object></div>
```

Source : [How to load an external webpage into a div of a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)

---

Method 2 (unsuccessful) :

```
<div id="help"><iframe src="http://matchhistory.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/EUW1/2468687321" height="500px" width="600px"></iframe></div>
```

Source : [Display the content of a div on another webpage in my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524568/display-the-content-of-a-div-on-another-webpage-in-my-website)

---

I'm kind of a beginner in various languages, I may be missing some basics.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you used your browser's debug tools to inspect the `iframe` to see if anything has loaded? You should also check the browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

That page has headers set that don't allow you to embed it.

"Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

I think you can get around this by using a HTTP requests.

Comment: Mmh i see, thanks. Any names of what type of HTTP requests and functions I'm looking for please ? :D